# How to obtain a position of last non-zero element

Tags: r, tidyverse, radix

I've got a binary variable representing if event happened or not:

```
event <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

I need to obtain a variable that would indicate the time when the last event happened. The expected output would be:

```
last_event <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 13, 13, 13, 13)
```

How can I obtain that with base R, tidyverse or any other way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that you have a binary vector, the following gives your desired output:

```
cummax(seq_along(event) * event)
```

Comment: Yes! So much more elegant than my solution. I was thinking about cumulative sums but I didn’t think of multiplying the indices by the binary vector.

Comment: or without multiplication `cummax(ifelse(event, seq_along(event), 0))`

Comment: @jogo That solution makes sense if the type of `event` is `logical`. It does work even for a numeric vector due to R’s implicit conversions but … eh.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you need to fill repetitions with a value, think [run-length encoding](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/rle.html).

In this case, you can determine the run lengths and then repeat the indices of `count == 0` an according number of times:

```
lengths = rle(event == 0)$lengths
nonzeros = which(event != 0)
runs = c(0, rep(nonzeros, each = 2))
result = rep(runs, lengths)
```

Alternative, substitute the runs in the RLE and then inverse it:

```
rle = rle(event == 0)
nonzeros = which(event != 0)
rle$values = c(0, rep(nonzeros, each = 2))
result = inverse.rle(rle)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do somthing like this-

```
> zero.locf <- function(x) {
  v <- x!=0
  c(0, x[v])[cumsum(v)+1]
}

> zero.locf(1:length(event)*event)

[1]  0  0  0  0  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 13 13 13 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to find the index where `event == 1` and repeat it based on `length`.

```
rep(c(0, which(event == 1)), tapply(event, cumsum(event == 1), length))
#[1]  0  0  0  0  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 13 13 13 13
```